# Generating animation from a list of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I have a list of pandas dataframes, with the dataframes representing subsequent frames in a process. As such, the dataframes are all of the same size and structure (same columns and indices). I am wondering if there is a way to animate these dataframes and save the animation as mpeg movie.

I have tried to do the following, however, did not have any luck:

```
#X: a list of 1000 dataframe, all of same size 
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

im = ax.imshow(X,interpolation='nearest')


def update_img(n):

    im.set_data(n.values)
    return im

animation = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,update_img, frames = X, interval=30)
```

the above gets stuck in the first frame.

Comment: The code from the question is working fine. You may want to provide  a [mcve] and clearly state how and where you run it and which version of the libraries you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save the animation as mp4, you can use

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)
import pandas as pd

X = [pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,10)) for i in range(100)] 
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

im = ax.imshow(X[0],interpolation='nearest')

def update_img(n):
    im.set_data(n.values)

ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig,update_img, frames = X, interval=30)

FFwriter = matplotlib.animation.FFMpegWriter(fps=30)     
ani.save(__file__+".mp4",writer = FFwriter)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! in "im = ax.imshow(X[0],interpolation='nearest')", I was passing the list X. I think this was the cause of the problem. thanks again!